# Alternatives to Hystrix for wrapping around a thrift client?

Tags: java, thrift, hystrix

I am looking at netflix's hystrix for wrapping around network calls.

With hystrix, you define a subclass of `HystrixCommand<E>` for each potential RPC command you need to use.

I have an apache thrift client set up which has many commands. Are there any alternatives to hystrix that allows me to easily wrap it around the entire client as opposed to having to define a `HystrixCommand` class for each function?

Comment: "*Are there any alternatives to hystrix*" - don't know of any (sorry) but this question in it's curent form is likely to being closed. Hystrix looks promising, BTW. I had that problem with a non-responding service just last week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter's Finagle is an alternative to Netflix's Hystrix.

Finagle creates an RPC for the whole client just as you need and of course Finagle talks Thrift and also Redis, MySQL, memcached and etc.

Finagle is created with Scala but it can also be used with Java (and all the JVM ecosystem languages like JRuby and Clojure)

Of course you can even use other languages outside the JVM since Finagle can talk Thrift and Thrift is available for a lot of other languages and platforms like Go, C# and even Objective-C for use it in an iPhone or iPad as client instead of slow Json/HTTP calls.

More info about Finagle here -> https://twitter.github.io/finagle/guide/ and here an starting project sample with Finagle Maven and Java -> https://github.com/csaltos/hello-finagle-maven

Comment: Here a sample on how to use Finagle with Maven and Java -> https://github.com/csaltos/hello-finagle-maven

Answer (score 1):

I am also looking for a hystrix like circuit breaker solution for thrift clients. Will try out Phantom (https://github.com/flipkart/phantom) which is providing a thrift proxy with hystrix under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

In the project I am working on, I have hundreds of integrations of various types, and I wanted a generic solution that would allow me to apply a circuit breaker to any of them. To do that, I am using `org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory`, and a custom class wrapping the `HystrixCommand` which implements `org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor`. Any dynamic proxy implementation should work, though.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [resilience4j](https://resilience4j.github.io/resilience4j/).

> In Hystrix calls to external systems have to be wrapped in a HystrixCommand. This library, in contrast, provides higher-order functions (decorators) to enhance any functional interface, lambda expression or method reference with a Circuit Breaker, Rate Limiter or Bulkhead.